# Excluding rows dynamically

Tags: dynamic, google-sheets, average, rows

Let's assume we have the following:

```
    A
1   10  
2   20  
3   30  
4   20  
5   10  
6   30  
7   20  
8
9
10  =(AVERAGE(A1:A7)
11  4
12  6
```

I would like to be able to find a way to calculate the Average of A1-A7 into cell A10 while excluding row range defined in A11 and A12. That is, according to the above setup the result should be `20`:

```
((10 + 20 + 30 + 20) / 4) = 20
```

because if rows 4,5 and 6 are excluded what's left is rows 1,2,3,7 to be averaged.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? If you set the range to be `A1:A7`, the rest is ignored anyhow.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I mean that I want to make an average of values form A1:A7 and have a way to ignore some values in that range. The ignore range is specified in A11 and A12 cells. The purpose of this is to build a simulator of a larger system, and program some cells as control elements for experimentation. That's why I want it to be highly dynamic.

Comment: +1; now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to meet your requirement, though not flexible:

```
=(sum(A1:A7)-indirect("A"&A11)-indirect("A"&A12))/(count(A1:A7)-2)
```

Adjust re misunderstanding of requirements:

```
=(SUM(A1:A7)-SUM(INDIRECT("A"&A11&":A"&A12)))/(COUNT(A1:A7)-A12+A11-1)
```

Comment: I think you're answer is pretty close, but instead of subtracting each cell deduced by A11 and A12, I would like to subtract the range. In this case,  I need to skip row index: 4-5-6. Optimally, instead of -2 at the end, it should be a dynamic value.

Answer (score 1):

Two other options:

`=AVERAGE(FILTER(A1:A7,ISNA(MATCH(ROW(A1:A7),A11:A12,0))))`

`=ArrayFormula(AVERAGEIF(MATCH(ROW(A1:A7),A11:A12,0),NA(),A1:A7))`

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify the expected result. Maybe you could take another look at it. Thanks